# Place #define in structure

Tags: c

From linux kernel code

```
struct gpio_desc {
    struct gpio_chip    *chip;
    unsigned long       flags;
/* flag symbols are bit numbers */
#define FLAG_REQUESTED  0
#define FLAG_IS_OUT 1
#define FLAG_EXPORT 2   /* protected by sysfs_lock */
#define FLAG_SYSFS  3   /* exported via /sys/class/gpio/control */
#define FLAG_ACTIVE_LOW 6   /* value has active low */
#define FLAG_OPEN_DRAIN 7   /* Gpio is open drain type */
#define FLAG_OPEN_SOURCE 8  /* Gpio is open source type */
#define FLAG_USED_AS_IRQ 9  /* GPIO is connected to an IRQ */
#define FLAG_IS_HOGGED  11  /* GPIO is hogged */

    /* Connection label */
    const char      *label;
    /* Name of the GPIO */
    const char      *name;
};
```

what is the reason to place defines into the body of structure?

Comment: What's wrong with that? Maybe to have the constants close to where they are used.

Comment: This is ok, I guess, when the structure has only one field that needs `#defines`. Seems like the structure definition would be a mess if you had half-a-dozen fields each with 10 defines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `#define` it doesn't matter too much where you put them (so long as it is higher up in the file than where it is first used).  Most likely those constants are used only within that structure, so it was put there so logically they would be easier to find.  They could have been put anywhere above the first place they were used, but they were grouped together because of similar purpose.

Comment: I guess it's just to sel-document the `flags` field.

Answer (score 4):

It's meaningless, other than to try and define them close to the point of first use.

By the time the compiler actually sees the code, the preprocessor will have stripped those lines out of it.

In this particular example, they would be better off with a typedef'd enum for the flags and using that enum to declare the field.

Comment: `#define` is often preferrable over `enum`. For example when the numerical value is used for some kind of calculation.

Comment: Only if those calculations are in preprocessor directives. Everywhere else, enum converts quietly to to int (in C).

Comment: Not quietly. You will get warnings telling that `enum` type is mixed with some other type.

Comment: Not always. With gcc 4.8.4. I can do `1 << BIT3` without any warnings (even with `-Wall` specificed)

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on the compiler or perhaps the nature of operation performed. But yeah, it is definitely allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

There is no impact.
But in the example, for readability sake they maintained/added near to the variable declared.

They want use those "#define" for the variable "unsigned long       flags;".

Below is simple example and proves no impact on the class/struct by declaring the "#Define" inside.

```
//gcc 4.9.3

#include  <stdio.h>

struct gpio_desc {

#define FLAG_REQUESTED  0

} test;

int main()
{
    printf("%d",FLAG_REQUESTED);
}
```

The out put is zero.

Comment: This is a question about C, not C++.  Your example uses a C++ header, and creates an empty struct which is not allowed in C (though it is valid to create an empty class in C++), and it uses C++ I/O.  All of which adds up to an inappropriate answer for a C question.

Comment: @Jonathan The above code is allowed in gcc 4.9.3. I mean empty struct. Try here http://rextester.com/l/c_online_compiler_gcc

Comment: I guess the GCC 4.9.3 comment allows you to use a GCC extension to standard C and claim it is OK.  Empty structure types are not allowed in Standard C — still.  And a `#define` in the middle doesn't make it any less empty.  Compile with `-pedantic` and you'll get a warning or error about the problem.

Comment: Could be. I will give a try.

Comment: It allowed the code #include  <stdio.h>

struct gpio_desc {



} test;

int main()
{
   return 0;
}

Comment: But the size of empty struct in C is zero. Where as the size of empty struct in C++ is one. (tested with GCC compiler)

Comment: OK.  Then if GCC allows it, GCC has a bug of sorts.  I'm away from a computer at the moment, so I can't check myself just yet.  Are you compiling with `gcc` or `g++`, and are you changing the file name so it has a `.c` extension?  If it has a C++ extension, `gcc` will compile it as C++.

Comment: "gcc" for "C" code and "g++" for "C++" code. But I got the warning in "C" and allowed  to print output.

Comment: Found some documentation in GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html